# Best way to close the stream during bulk upload

Tags: java, java-io, box-api

I'm uploading bulk files (say 50000) to Box through Box Java API's. To do that we call the uploadFile method 50000 times. The method also creates and close the file input stream.

Is there a way to keep the stream open until the bulk load is done? Even if I close the stream in finally block, it will close it every time I call the method.

```
private static String uploadFile(String pathFileName, BoxAPIConnection api, BoxFolder folder) {
    boolean fileExists = false;
    String fileId = null;
    FileInputStream stream = null;
    log.debug("Invoked uploadFileAsBoxAppUser-uploadFile :" + pathFileName + ":" + api + ":" + folder);
    try {
        String fileName = pathFileName.substring(pathFileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, pathFileName.length());
        log.debug("fileName :" + fileName);

        for (BoxItem.Info itemInfo : folder) {
            if (itemInfo instanceof BoxFile.Info) {
                BoxFile.Info fileInfo = (BoxFile.Info) itemInfo;
                if (fileName.equals(fileInfo.getName())) {
                    fileExists = true;
                    fileId = fileInfo.getID();
                    log.debug("fileExists in Destination box Folder fileID " + fileId);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!fileExists) {
            log.debug("uploading new file: " + fileName);
            stream = new FileInputStream(pathFileName);
            BoxFile.Info boxInfo = folder.uploadFile(stream, pathFileName);
            fileId = boxInfo.getID();
        } else {
            log.debug("uploading new version of file: " + fileName);
            BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, fileId);
            stream = new FileInputStream(pathFileName);
            file.uploadVersion(stream);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.debug("Exception in uploadFileAsBoxAppUser :" + e);
    }
    finally {
        if (stream != null)
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return fileId;
}
```